# Python 3.3 TKinter image doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tk-toolkit

I am trying to open an image with ImageTk.PhotoImage from PIL but I keep hitting the same error. I have the image and can see that it is there when it downloads it, it opens it, but then I get the error that it is not there.

Here is the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "S:/Projects/xmlParser.py", line 128, in updateSelected
    self.threadLabelImage.config(text = self.threadImage)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1263, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1254, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

Relevant Code

```
        if self.threadLinkList[self.y].find('imgur') != -1:
        url =  self.threadLinkList[self.y]+'.gif'
        imageName=self.threadLinkList[self.y][-11:-4]+'.gif'

        print(imageName)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(self.threadLinkList[self.y],imageName)

        imgfile = Image.open(imageName)
        imgfile = imgfile.resize((150,150),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        # img = Image.open(file)

        print(imgfile)
        self.threadImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgfile)

        self.threadLabelImage.config(text = self.threadImage)
        self.threadImage.image = imgfile
```

Entire program to run.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import webbrowser,time,urllib.request,re,os
import tkinter as tk
import urllib
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

main = tk.Tk()
os.getcwd()
class Application(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.threadTitle = tk.StringVar()
        self.threadAuth = tk.StringVar()
        self.threadPub = tk.StringVar()
        self.threadArtLink = tk.StringVar()
        self.threadLink = tk.StringVar()
        self.threadImg = tk.StringVar()
        self.threadArtLink.set('Click something to display thread info')
        photo = Image.open("temp.png")
        photo = photo.resize((150,150), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.threadImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)



        # Intializes tkinter gui framework
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        # Packs widgets needed
        self.grid()
        # Creates the widgets functions
        self.createWidgets()
        # Intializes the man rss.xml
        self.initial()
        # self.threadLabelArtLink = None
        # self.threadLabelTitle = None
        # self.threadLabelThreadLink = None
        # self.threadLabelArtLink = None
        # self.threadImgLink = None

    def createWidgets(self):
        # Create entrybox and align to grid
        self.send_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.send_entry.grid(row=0,column=0)

        # Create button,allign to grid, get xml
        self.change_sub = tk.Button(self,text='Change Subreddit',padx=5, pady=5, command=lambda :self.getXML(self.send_entry.get()))
        self.change_sub.grid(row=0 , column=3)

        # Create scrollbar on Y-Axis
        self.lb_scrollY = tk.Scrollbar(self,orient=tk.VERTICAL)

        # On grid next to Listbox(sticky means fill whole row
        self.lb_scrollY.grid(row=1,column=4,sticky=tk.NS,rowspan=6)

        # Create Listbox and get Y from scrollbar
        self.thread_lb = tk.Listbox(self,yscrollcommand=self.lb_scrollY.set,height=20)

        # Calls function whenever a new item is selected & open thread if double click 1
        self.thread_lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',self.updateSelected)
        self.thread_lb.bind('<Double-Button-1>',self.openPage)

        # scrolly will change the view of listbox
        self.lb_scrollY['command']=self.thread_lb.yview
        self.thread_lb.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=tk.NS+tk.EW,columnspan=4)

        self.threadFrame = tk.LabelFrame(main,text='Reddit',width=450,height=350,labelanchor='n')

        self.threadLabelTitle = tk.Label(self.threadFrame,textvariable=self.threadTitle,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5)
        self.threadLabelTitle.grid(row=1,column=10,sticky= tk.EW)

        self.threadLabelAuth = tk.Label(self.threadFrame, textvariable=self.threadAuth,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5)
        self.threadLabelAuth.grid(row=2,column=10,sticky = tk.EW)

        self.threadLabelPub = tk.Label(self.threadFrame, textvariable=self.threadPub,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5)
        self.threadLabelPub.grid(row=3,column=10,sticky = tk.EW)

        self.threadLabelArtLink = tk.Label(self.threadFrame, textvariable=self.threadArtLink,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5)
        self.threadLabelArtLink.grid(row=4,column=10,sticky = tk.EW)

        self.threadLabelThreadLink = tk.Label(self.threadFrame, textvariable=self.threadLink,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5)
        self.threadLabelThreadLink.grid(row=5,column=10,sticky = tk.EW)

        self.threadImgLink = tk.Label(self.threadFrame, textvariable=self.threadImg,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5)
        self.threadImgLink.grid(row=6,column=10,sticky = tk.EW)

        self.threadLabelImage = tk.Label(self.threadFrame,image=self.threadImage,wraplength=400,padx=20,pady=5)
        self.threadLabelImage.grid(row=7,column=10,sticky = tk.EW)

        self.threadFrame.grid(row=0,column=10,sticky=tk.EW,rowspan=8)



        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=main.destroy,padx=5, pady=5)
        self.QUIT.grid(row=7)
        self.threadFrame.grid_propagate(0)


    def updateSelected(self, event):
        # getting selected listbox item
        i=self.thread_lb.curselection()
        # Returns tuple that must be split
        x,self.y,z = re.split("\D+",str(i))
        self.y=int(self.y)
        print(self.threadTitleList[self.y])
        print(self.threadPubDateList[self.y])
        print(self.threadLinkList[self.y])
        print(self.threadDescList[self.y])
        self.threadTitle.set(self.threadTitleList[self.y])
        self.threadAuth.set(self.threadAuthList[self.y])
        self.threadPub.set(self.threadPubDateList[self.y])
        self.threadArtLink.set(self.threadLinkList[self.y])
        self.threadLink.set(self.threadDescList[self.y])
        # self.threadImg.set('Will put image here')
        if self.threadLinkList[self.y].find('imgur') != -1:
            url =  self.threadLinkList[self.y]+'.gif'
            imageName=self.threadLinkList[self.y][-11:-4]+'.gif'

            print(imageName)
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(self.threadLinkList[self.y],imageName)

            imgfile = Image.open(imageName)
            imgfile = imgfile.resize((150,150),Image.ANTIALIAS)
            # img = Image.open(file)

            print(imgfile)
            self.threadImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgfile)

            self.threadLabelImage.config(text = self.threadImage)
            self.threadImage.image = imgfile


        # # threadTitle = self.threadTitleList[y]
        # print(self.threadLabelTitle["text"])
        # # self.threadLabelTitle['text']=threadTitle
        # self.threadLabelAutPub['text']=self.threadPubDateList[y]
        # self.threadImgLink['text']=self.threadLinkList[y]
        # self.threadLabelThreadLink['text']=self.threadDescList[y]
        # main.update()

    def openPage(self,event):
        webbrowser.get('windows-default').open_new(self.threadLinkList[self.y])

    def descStripper(self,desc):
        # Intialize values
        l1,l2,l2Start = 0,0,0
        t1,t2,t2start = 0,0,0
        link = ""
        thread = ""

        # Where to start looking for each in description element
        l1=int(desc.find('<br/> <a href="'))
        t1=int(desc.find('</a> <a href="'))
        a1=int(desc.find('"> '))

        # If both of the tags are found then continue
        if l1 != -1 and t1 != -1 and a1 != 1:
            # Start looking for end of quotes 16 characters from beginning of tag
            l2Start = l1+16
            l2=int(desc.find('"',l2Start))
            # Link is created from what is in the quotes
            link = desc[l1+15:l2]

            # Same as above but to find thread link
            t2start = t1+15
            t2=int(desc.find('"',t2start))
            thread = desc[t1+14:t2]

            a2start = a1+4
            a2 = int(desc.find(' <',a2start))
            author = desc[a1+3:a2]
            return link,thread,author
        else:
            # If it can't find one it will return an error
            link = "Couldn't find the stuff :("
            thread = "Couldn't find the thread link :("
            return link, thread

    def lbPopulator(self,title,pub,link):
        # Delete old entries from listbox
        self.thread_lb.delete(0,tk.END)
        # Iterate through all the items and append them to the listbox
        for item in title:
            self.thread_lb.insert(tk.END,item)

    def getXmlData(self):
        # Intialize lists
        self.threadPubDateList = []
        self.threadTitleList = []
        self.threadLinkList = []
        self.threadDescList = []
        self.threadThumbNailList = []
        self.threadAuthList = []
        # Use the downloaded rss.xml for XML parsing
        tree=ET.parse('rss.xml')
        # define root as the base of the XML parsing tree
        root=tree.getroot()
        for channel in root:
            # Iterate through all the channels
            for SubChannel in channel:
                # Iterate through all the items in the channel
                if SubChannel.tag == 'item':
                    # If the SubChannel is called item then search for the items below
                    for threadInfo in SubChannel:
                        # iterate through all the items in the 'item'
                        if threadInfo.tag == 'title':
                            # append the tag from the title to the list
                            self.threadTitleList.append(threadInfo.text)
                        if threadInfo.tag == 'pubDate':
                            #  Append the pubdate info to the list but remove excess characters
                            self.threadPubDateList.append(threadInfo.text[:-6])
                        if threadInfo.tag == 'description':
                            # Pass all the information from the description to the stripper to get the useful
                            # information and links
                            link,thread,author = self.descStripper(threadInfo.text)
                            self.threadLinkList.append(link)
                            self.threadDescList.append(thread)
                            self.threadAuthList.append(author)
                        # if threadInfo.tag == ''
            # Populate the listbox with the newly generated lists
        self.lbPopulator(self.threadTitleList,self.threadPubDateList,self.threadLinkList)

    def getXML(self,subreddit):
        try:
            # Try to download the xml file using the user input subreddit
            url = 'http://www.reddit.com'+subreddit+'.rss'
            source = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,'rss.xml')
            self.getXmlData()
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
            # Error caused by reddit API limiting connections
            print('Too many requests-Try again')

    def initial(self):
        try:
            # Same as above but downloads the front page
            source = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.reddit.com/.rss','rss.xml')
            self.getXmlData()
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
            print('Too many requests-Trying again 3')
            # If error occurs program waits 3 seconds and then restarts
            time.sleep(3)
            self.__init__()

# main.geometry("350x400")
app = Application(master=main)
# Begins the applications GUI loop

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is not a file-not-found error telling you the GIF file doesn't exist, it's an error from Tk telling you that PIL didn't pass the image correctly. (PIL/Tkinter is supposed to put a reference to the image in a Tcl variable, then tell Tcl/Tk to use that variable; it either didn't do the first step, did it but then unset the variable, or used the wrong name.) The first question is: which versions are you using? In particular, if you're not using Pillow 2.0 or later for your PIL, do that first.

Comment: I am using Pillow 2.2.2

Comment: Meanwhile, instead of pasting your entire program and then trying to highlight the relevant part, create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that only has the relevant part and whatever boilerplate is necessary to get it to run and reproduce your error. When I run your program, and create an image file named `temp.png`, that image definitely gets displayed, but I have no idea if that's the part you're having problems with.

Comment: Finally, as a side note on tags: if you're using Python 3.x, put that in a tag rather than in the text of your code (besides the fact that that's conceptually better, there are many people here who will not notice it otherwise and will give you irrelevant answers about the `SyntaxError`s they get trying to run your code in 2.7), and don't use the `tcl` tag unless you're actually looking to write/debug some Tcl code; the fact that Tkinter happens to use Tcl under the covers isn't important.

Comment: I figured it out. I was trying to apply the picture to the text attrib to the text attribute of the label and not the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was attempting to apply the image to the text attribute of the label instaed of the image. Here is the fixed code.

```
        url =  self.threadLinkList[self.y]+'.gif'
        imageName=self.threadLinkList[self.y][-11:-4]+'.gif'

        print(imageName)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(self.threadLinkList[self.y],imageName)

        imgfile = Image.open(imageName)
        imgfile = imgfile.resize((150,150),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        # img = Image.open(file)

        print(imgfile)
        self.threadImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgfile)

        self.threadLabelImage.config(***image*** = self.threadImage)
        self.threadImage.image = imgfile
```